# WebDriver i am trying to use isElementPresent but error shows not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am new to WebDriver and writing this code in C# Visual Studio (code snippet below)
I am verifying if a text field is present on the home page using IsElementPresent.
I get the error The name IsElementPresent does not exist in the current context.
What am i doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace Homepage_check2
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Driver
    {
        IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }

        [Test]
        public void homepage()
        {
            //Navigate to the site
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.milkround.com");

           Assert.IsTrue(IsElementPresent(By.Id("ctl00_uxToolbar_uxQueryTextBoxToolbar")));

        }
        catch
        {
            //verificationErrors.Append(e.Message);
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use the IDE to generate this code? Have you done before? The error means there is no method called "IsElementPresent", which there isn't. At least, not in the code you have shown us. However Selenium IDE commonly creates this for you, so I am assuming you are getting things mixed up a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does "IsElementPresent" come from?  I have never seen that used in WebDriver.

In WebDriver you need to do wrap a try catch around the findElement method.

e.g

```
Boolean elementDisplayed;

try {

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.Id("ctl00_uxToolbar_uxQueryTextBoxToolbar"));
elementDisplayed = element.displayed; 

}
catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
elementDisplayed = false;
}
```

Obviously you can wrap this in a helper method of some kind of perhaps add it to the WebDriver classes.

I'll leave that to you, but this is the general idea

Comment: Thanks the findElement works.  isElementPresent came from the selenium IDE -> option in ide to convert to webDriver code